# how to upgrade ubuntu12.04 to ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 12.04, 13.04

how to upgrade ubuntu 12.04 to 13.04. What is the difference of these versions.  after ending the support of 13.04 what we have to do?

Comment: Please do read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading

Answer (score 0):

You need to first upgrade 12.04 to 12.10. Then you can upgrade it using `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` or you can try this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RaringUpgrades. This might also help you [can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading).